# How and when did David kill Mr. Peterson's boss?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-guest

Mr. Peterson's boss is the only death in *The Guest* (2014) that wasn't shown on screen. I can't figure out how David could've fit this in his schedule:

- Day 1: David meets everyone in Caleb's family. Dad told him about his boss.
- Day 2: Picks up Luke, fights with the bullies, goes to the party
- Day 3: Kills the gun dealer & friend, frames Anna's bf. Dad comes home and says his boss has been missing for a few days and was just found dead.

There's no way David could've killed the boss on day 1. If he somehow did kill him on the night on day 2, then the boss would've missed work only one day on day 3. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Good question. But remind me (I honestly don't remember) why he couldn't have snuck out and kill the boss on day one. Then what Mr. Peterson said could be technically true ("He'd been missing from work for **a couple of days**")

Comment: Mr. P told David about his job situation just before the bed time. The only thing he told David about his boss is his name. I don't know how David figured out where he lived? Mr. P himself wouldn't know the exact address. Even if he somehow found out where he lived, David doesn't have a car so he would've had to steal the keys to one of the family cars. He would've also woken up the family driving out of the garage so late at night. I don't know lol.